# Android Navigation Drawer second Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I already create my application with Navigation Drawer. I want to start my second activity and keep the navigation drawer.
When, i opened my second activity using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

The Navigation Drawer disapper.

So, how can i do this?

Comment: why don't you just use the fragment from the frame in the navigation drawer activity's main layout? Take a look here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: You only create NavigationDrawers on a "per activity basis". So one option: *copy everything related to the drawer* from MainActivity to SecondActivity. The other option: in this SO question, OP has a *NavigationDrawer parent activity* and all other activities extend that activity. Or, of course: *use fragments* as @Nasz Njoka Sr. suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Try these code :-

we need to call fragment that's why we will use these code

> FragmentTransaction ftHome =
>   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>           Fragment fmHome = new HomeFragment();
>
> ```
>     ftHome.replace(R.id.container_body, fmHome);
>     ftHome.commit();
> ```

Comment: can you please explain how this code will solve the problem?